# Cadastro de usuários com adm logado

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com Laravel e tenho o seguinte objetivo: Fazer com que apenas o usuário administrador consiga cadastrar novos usuários. Meu problema não é bloquear o acesso de usuários comuns ao cadastro de usuários e sim fazer com que o cadastro de usuários seja acessível com o Administrador logado, pois no laravel como padrão o cadastro de usuários acontece sem o usuário estar logado e quando eu coloco um botão dentro do sistema direcionando para o cadastro de usuários ele bloqueia, redireciona para a home. No caso meu sistema está todo pronto, falta apenas o cadastro de usuários ser acessível. Espero que eu tenha deixado claro meu problema.

**Função Cadastro:**

```
public function salvar()
{
    $name = request()->input('name');
    $email = request()->input('email');
    $password = request()->input('password');

    $passwords = bcrypt($password);

    DB::insert('INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', array($name, $email, $passwords));

    return redirect() ->action('HomeController@index');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você criar uma nova rota para cadastrar os usuários, e não usar a rota padrão. Por exemplo:

```
Route::post('admin/user/save', 'UserController@save')->name('admin.user.save');
```

UserController:

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $response = [
            'success' => false
        ];

        $data = $request->all();

        $params = [
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
        ];

        $user = User::create($params);

        if ($user) {
            $response = [
                'success' => true
            ];
        }
        return redirect()->action('HomeController@index')->with($response);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

E na sua `view`, você pode tratar o retorno caso `success` seja `true` ou `false`, para exibir uma mensagem de sucesso ou erro.

O Método save é apenas um exemplo, devem ser implementados mais tratamentos de acordo com a sua necessidade, caso vá criar uma senha para ele nesse momento, tem que usar o método `Hash::make($data['password'])` entre outras particularidades que você deve tiver em seu cadastro.

Comment: eu tinha começado a fazer isso, só que como eu teria que criar outro controller pro register eu teria que utilizar o mesmo método de criptografia do laravel q é a bcrypt, só que eu não sei usar esse método de criptografia... Mas valeu pela tua resposta, vou procurar entender como funciona o bcrypt.

Comment: é como disse ali, você pode usar o `Hash:make` para criptografar a senha, dê uma olhada na documentação.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing

Comment: é que fiz diferente minha estrutura de cadastro, vou colocar junto com a pergunta, mas funcionou legal.

Comment: funciona não kkk esquece

Comment: Pois é, tente fazer algo parecido com minha resposta, vou modificar de acordo com o que eu entendo que possa ser sua necessidade

Comment: agora funcionou, coloquei $passwords = bcrypt($password); dps passei $passwords no array

Comment: Boa @João.Mistura, editei a minha resposta, acho que pode utilizar daquela maneira, para não precisar criar uma query dentro de sua controller

Comment: blzz, @arllondias valeu